# Syntax Error in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm new to the language and trying to figure out the formatting for a simple function that returns the roots of a quadratic equation.

```
    discriminant(A,B,C) -> 
        B * B - 4 * A * C.

    get_roots(A,B,C) when A == 0 -> error;
    get_roots(A,B,C) when discriminant(A,B,C) == 0  -> [(-B/(2*A))];
    get_roots(A,B,C) when discriminant(A,B,C) > 0   -> 
        D = discriminant(A,B,C);
        [((-1 * B + math:sqrt(D)) / 2 * A), ((-1 * B - math:sqrt(D)) / 2 * A)];
    get_roots(A,B,C) when discriminant(A,B,C) < 0   -> [].
```

What is the syntactical mistake that I've made? The error that I get when I enter "c(ps04)" in the shell, where ps04.erl is the file in which I wrote my function, is:

```
    ps04.erl:15: syntax error before: '['
    ps04.erl:23: Warning: variable 'Head' is unused %for a different function defined later
    error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a function in guard, so `get_roots(A,B,C) when discriminant(A,B,C) == 0` is forbidden.
 AS mention by @Amon there is a semicolon that should be replaced by a comma. I would write the function like this:

```
get_roots(0,0,_) -> [];
get_roots(0,B,C) -> [-C/B];
get_roots(A,B,C) -> get_roots(A,B,C,A*A-4*B*C).

get_roots(A,B,C,0) -> [-B/(2*A)];
get_roots(A,B,C,D) when D > 0 ->
    RD = math:sqrt(D),
    [(-B+RD)/(2*A),(-B-RD)/(2*A)];
get_roots(_,_,_,_) -> [].
```

Comment: I've been doing Haskell for so long I've forgotten about the small number of BIFs that you CAN use in guards... It's time Erlang tended to that issue...

Answer (score 4):

You should replace the semicolon in `D = discriminant(A,B,C);` with a comma:
`D = discriminant(A,B,C),`.

By having a semicolon, you're ending this specific `get_roots/3` function clause, which is not what you want (you have an additional clause below it obviously).

On a side note, I've noticed from two of your other questions that you have never accepted an answer. If someone has answered your question and it is a valid solution, click the checkmark next to that answer.